# What is the difference between JQuery UI autocomplete "multiple values" and "multiple, remote"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using a JQuery UI autocomplete filter in my project and I want the user to be able to input multiple items from a database on a server.  I am sort of confused as to what the difference is between JQuery UI autocomplete "multiple values" and "multiple, remote" and which would be best suited for my project?  Thanks.

Comment: you'll most likely need a combination of the two.

Comment: Can you explain the difference of the two and what each is best suited for?  Thanks

Comment: Each are just examples. One example shows you how to use two different remote sources, the other shows how to allow the user to select two or more values. You'll need to be able to select two or more values AND use a remote source. The difference is they are two different examples! They each have a different goal.

Comment: You say "[it] shows you how to use two different remote sources", but I will only be using one, so will I still need to use this?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Nope. you'll just need the single remote source.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple** -- Let's you select multiple values.

**Multiple remote** - It just mean's that you are loading the autocomplete result's from remote server :

Example -

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, response );
        },
```

*I want the user to be able to input multiple items from a database on a server.*

see this : 
[jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple-remote.html](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/multiple-remote.html)

Comment: so the difference between multiple values and multiple remote is that they both allow for multiple inputs by the user, but the autocomplete list is local when using multiple values and on a server when using multiple remote?

Comment: So to clarify, I won't need to do what @Kevin B said in a comment in my original post and use both?  I will only need to use multiple remote, correct?

Comment: Yes you need multiple remote-